# Minecraft can't load any other version

Tags: minecraft

When I try to play either 1.14, 1.14-optifine or 1.13 it works perfectly fine, however when I play any older version or with any client (like forge) it crashes instantly. It doesn't even make a crash log.

OpenJDK info:

openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)